# Fill double dimension string tab in Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I'm trying to adapt a DB request to a String[][] type. This is what i try to do but my app crash saying that i try to fill a Null tab. I'm probably doing something stupid but i'm used to C logic.

Here is my function to do it

```
public void putList(int listsize) {

    String [][] clubResultAndWins = new String[listsize][];
    for (int i = 0; i < listsize; i++)
    {
        clubResultAndWins[i][0] = list.get(i).getCompleteName();
        clubResultAndWins[i][1] = list.get(i).getRank().toString();
    }
}
```

And this don't work, it need to have an equivalent of this:

```
String[][] clubResultandWins = new String[][]{

  {"Complete name", "Rank"},

  {"Complete name", "Rank"},

  {"Complete name", "Rank"}};
```

This must be simple. Thank for help.

Comment: How did you fill the values in list?

Comment: "list" is a     List<Object>     type, retrieved from JSon using retrofit.

Comment: I know that but there must be some methods for setCompleteName() and setRank() where are they?

Comment: On my POJO models. They simply return string, and theses works perfectly.

The problem was solved by nbokmans below. Thanks for you help Osama !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to set a length for the second array of clubResultAndWins. You can fix this by changing:

```
String [][] clubResultAndWins = new String[listsize][];
```

to:

```
String [][] clubResultAndWins = new String[listsize][2];
```

Comment: This is what i did at the very first time, but it didn't worked. I must have did something wrong because you're way works perfectly.

Thanks.